How can i print only text in a respond LlamaIndex prompt
I created a file that works with receive some answer message Then will reply to the answer message according to the prompt given. The results came out very good. But there are some symbols that I don't want to show. I want to show only the answer. This is my code
const { OpenAI } = require("llamaindex");

async function summarizeResponse(responseText) {
    const llm = new OpenAI({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        additionalChatOptions: { response_format: { type: "json_object" } },
    });

    const example = {
        summary: "",
    };

    const response = await llm.chat({
        messages: [
            {
                role: "system",
                content: `Your name is ComputerAI , You are an expert assistant for give infomation about specification computer.
                tell what your name and answer the same responsetext but last word is 'kub pom' 
                \n\nGenerate a valid JSON in the following format:\n\n${JSON.stringify(example)} and answer your response in that`,
            },
            {
                role: "user",
                content: `Here is the responsetext: \n------\n${responseText}\n------`,
            },
        ],
    });

    const text = await response.message.content

    return text;
}


module.exports = { summarizeResponse };


Its working is something like this.
User : Hi
Chatbot : {"summary":"Hello! How can I assist you kub pom"} 
As you can see, I don't need any marks in this answer. I only want the answer text.
I tried writing a prompt to create json like in this example.
and will return the value as text = await response.message.content.summary
text = await response.message.content.summary 
And of course it's an error. I don't know how to fix this code. Can someone please tell me how? Thank you for reading and I would be delighted if you could fix this code quickly.
Its working is something like this.
User : Hi
Chatbot : {"summary":"Hello! How can I assist you kub pom"} 
As you can see, I don't need any marks in this answer. I only want the answer text.
I tried writing a prompt to create json like in this example.
and will return the value as text = await response.message.content.summary
text = await response.message.content.summary 
And of course it's an error. I don't know how to fix this code. Can someone please tell me how? Thank you for reading and I would be delighted if you could fix this code quickly.

I don't understand which part is wrong. Can you please clarify?
I think you need to describe clearly: 1. which prompt are you sending 2. which reply are you receiving 3. which part of the reply should not be included.
It is not clear from your question.
